# Excel SUMIF equivalent in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sumifs

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 201901, 10, 201801, 201801], 
                   ['B', 201902, 11, 201801, 201802], 
                   ['B', 201903, 13, 201801, 201803],
                   ['B', 201905, 18, 201801, 201805],
                   ['A', 201906, 80, 201801, 201806],
                   ['A', 202001, 10, 201901, 201901], 
                   ['A', 202002, 11, 201901, 201902], 
                   ['A', 202003, 13, 201901, 201903],
                   ['A', 202004, 18, 201901, 201904],
                   ['B', 202005, 80, 201901, 201905],
                   ['A', 202006, 80, 201901, 201906],
                   ['B', 201901, 10, 201801, 201801], 
                   ['A', 201902, 11, 201801, 201802], 
                   ['A', 201903, 13, 201801, 201803],
                   ['A', 201905, 18, 201801, 201805],
                   ['B', 201906, 80, 201801, 201806],
                   ['B', 202001, 10, 201901, 201901], 
                   ['B', 202002, 11, 201901, 201902], 
                   ['B', 202003, 13, 201901, 201903],
                   ['B', 202004, 18, 201901, 201904],
                   ['A', 202005 ,80, 201901, 201905],
                   ['B', 202006 ,80, 201901, 201906]],
                  columns = ['Store','yearweek','sales','Start_PY','PY'])
df
```

From the `df` **(note that week 201904 is missing)** above I would like to add a column `'Sales_PY'` with on each line the sum of sales in the previous yearweeks per store.
Something like this:

| Store | yearweek | sales | Start_PY | PY | sales_PY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 201901 | 100 | 201801 | 201801 | NaN |
| B | 201902 | 11 | 201801 | 201802 | NaN |
| B | 201903 | 13 | 201801 | 201803 | NaN |
| B | 201905 | 18 | 201801 | 201805 | NaN |
| A | 201906 | 800 | 201801 | 201806 | NaN |
| A | 202001 | 100 | 201901 | 201901 | 100.0 |
| A | 202002 | 110 | 201901 | 201902 | 210.0 |
| A | 202003 | 130 | 201901 | 201903 | 340.0 |
| A | 202004 | 180 | 201901 | 201904 | 340.0 |
| B | 202005 | 80 | 201901 | 201905 | 52.0 |
| A | 202006 | 800 | 201901 | 201906 | 1320.0 |
| B | 201901 | 10 | 201801 | 201801 | NaN |
| A | 201902 | 110 | 201801 | 201802 | NaN |
| A | 201903 | 130 | 201801 | 201803 | NaN |
| A | 201905 | 180 | 201801 | 201805 | NaN |
| B | 201906 | 80 | 201801 | 201806 | NaN |
| B | 202001 | 10 | 201901 | 201901 | 10.0 |
| B | 202002 | 11 | 201901 | 201902 | 21.0 |
| B | 202003 | 13 | 201901 | 201903 | 34.0 |
| B | 202004 | 18 | 201901 | 201904 | 34.0 |
| A | 202005 | 800 | 201901 | 201905 | 520.0 |
| B | 202006 | 80 | 201901 | 201906 | 132.0 |

And I think there must be a `SUMIF` equivalent from Excel within Pandas.

I.e. Sales PY for the last row would be SUM of sales WHERE store == 'B' AND yearweek >= 201901 AND yearweek <= 201906. This equals 132.

Because I can't ensure that my df will be arranged by store/week and I sometimes have weeks missing in my df I wouldn't prefer using the shift() and/or cumsum() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Completely replaced the answer following clarifications from OP

Note that the df you coded up is inconsistent with the df you printed in the table. I went with the one in the table

The below is not the most elegant but I cannot think of a more vectorized operation given missing weeks etc

We basically implement row-by-row calculation that follows `sumif` logic quite closely. The function in `apply` is applied to each row `r` For each row `r` it selects the relevant subset of the original dataframe `df` and calculates the sum

```
df['Sales_PY'] = (df.apply(lambda r: df.loc[(df['yearweek'] >= r['Start_PY'])
                                           &(df['yearweek'] <= r['PY']) 
                                           &(df['Store']==r['Store']) ,'sales'].sum(),axis=1)
                )
```

output

```
    Store      yearweek    sales    Start_PY      PY    Sales_PY
--  -------  ----------  -------  ----------  ------  ----------
 0  A            201901      100      201801  201801           0
 1  B            201902       11      201801  201802           0
 2  B            201903       13      201801  201803           0
 3  B            201905       18      201801  201805           0
 4  A            201906      800      201801  201806           0
 5  A            202001      100      201901  201901         100
 6  A            202002      110      201901  201902         210
 7  A            202003      130      201901  201903         340
 8  A            202004      180      201901  201904         340
 9  B            202005       80      201901  201905          52
10  A            202006      800      201901  201906        1320
11  B            201901       10      201801  201801           0
12  A            201902      110      201801  201802           0
13  A            201903      130      201801  201803           0
14  A            201905      180      201801  201805           0
15  B            201906       80      201801  201806           0
16  B            202001       10      201901  201901          10
17  B            202002       11      201901  201902          21
18  B            202003       13      201901  201903          34
19  B            202004       18      201901  201904          34
20  A            202005      800      201901  201905         520
21  B            202006       80      201901  201906         132
```

If you want `NaN`s instead of 0s where you do not have sales data you can pass `min_count=1` parameter in the `sum` above: `.sum(min_count=1)`

Comment: Thanks Piterbarg! But how can I obtain the same results when some weeks are missing? i.e. week 6 is not included in my df, I still want to sum week 4 - 6 (and not 3-5).

Comment: @BartBeckers pls see my edit -- is this more or less what you are after?

Comment: Not entirely, with this logic, if for example row 6 and 16 were excluded, I will get the sum of weeks 3, 4 and 5 while I still would like to have the sum of week 4, 5 and 6.
Furthermore, my real df is not (and will not be) arranged. Hence I wouldn't prefer the shift() function.

Comment: @BartBeckers  I must say it is not super clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve. Eg you do not need to 'arrange' your df ahead of time, the code above groups your df it by store, implicitly sorts by week and fills missing weeks with 0s.  To make progress may I suggest that your put a more representative example in your question with missing rows and what not, as well as expected output, so we can take it from there

Comment: I just edited my question. Note that week 201904 is missing. Is it now more clear what I am trying to achieve? Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @BartBeckers replaced the answer with what seems to be calculating the right thing now

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I needed. Many thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can group them by store and shift them forward one row, then group again and take the cumulative sum.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 4, 10, 3, 1], 
                   ['A', 5, 11, 4, 2], 
                   ['A', 6, 13, 5, 3],
                   ['A', 7, 18, 6, 4],
                   ['B', 4 ,80, 3, 1], 
                   ['B', 5, 78, 4, 2], 
                   ['B', 6, 71, 5, 3],
                   ['B', 7, 80, 6, 4]],
                  columns = ['Store','week','sales','week_min_1','week_min_3'])


df['sales_last_3_weeks'] = df.groupby('Store')['sales'].shift()
df['sales_last_3_weeks'] = df.groupby('Store')['sales_last_3_weeks'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Chris.
Is there also a way without the shift function, because this will cause problemens when my dataframe is not arranged properly or if I have missing weeks...
Furthermore, if I have more than 4 rows per store then the sumsum() function will sum all rows (not only the last 3).

Looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The dates seem to be uniform for Stores A and B; we can use an inequality join to get the relevant rows, sum the values with a groupby before merging back to the original dataframe. The [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) is helpful here for the non-equi merge, where we use binary search, instead of going through every row; depending on the data size, the performance may be helpful:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
dates = df.filter(like = 'PY').drop_duplicates()
left = df.loc[:, :"sales"]

outcome = (
          left.conditional_join(
              dates,
              ("yearweek", "Start_PY", ">="),
              ("yearweek", "PY", "<="),
              how="right",
          )
          .groupby(["Store", "Start_PY", "PY"])
          .sales.sum()
      )


# join back to the original dataframe
df.merge(
          outcome.rename("Sales_PY"),
          left_on=["Store", "Start_PY", "PY"],
          right_index=True,
          how="left",
      )


   Store  yearweek  sales  Start_PY      PY  Sales_PY
0      A    201901    100    201801  201801       NaN
1      B    201902     11    201801  201802       NaN
2      B    201903     13    201801  201803       NaN
3      B    201905     18    201801  201805       NaN
4      A    201906    800    201801  201806       NaN
5      A    202001    100    201901  201901     100.0
6      A    202002    110    201901  201902     210.0
7      A    202003    130    201901  201903     340.0
8      A    202004    180    201901  201904     340.0
9      B    202005     80    201901  201905      52.0
10     A    202006    800    201901  201906    1320.0
11     B    201901     10    201801  201801       NaN
12     A    201902    110    201801  201802       NaN
13     A    201903    130    201801  201803       NaN
14     A    201905    180    201801  201805       NaN
15     B    201906     80    201801  201806       NaN
16     B    202001     10    201901  201901      10.0
17     B    202002     11    201901  201902      21.0
18     B    202003     13    201901  201903      34.0
19     B    202004     18    201901  201904      34.0
20     A    202005    800    201901  201905     520.0
21     B    202006     80    201901  201906     132.0
```