Efficient excel SUMIF equivalent in Python
I am trying to figure out how to create the equivalent of SUMIF in Python. The solution I have currently works, but it is way too inefficient and it takes 20 minutes to run.
What would be the most efficient way to reach  the result that i want?
Here is the what I am doing currently boiled down to a very simple form. In the "real" code there are many more conditions.
**sales_data customer_1**
Transactions   | Product Dimension 4 | Product Dimension 2 | Product Dimension 3 | sum_of_sales
-------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | --------------------| -------------
1              | 50                  | F80                 | ETQ546              | 80
2              | 50                  | F80                 | SAS978              | 20
3              | 50                  | C36                 | JBH148              | 10
4              | 50                  | F80                 | ETQ546              | 80
5              | 50                  | F80                 | SAS978              | 20
6              | 50                  | C36                 | JBH148              | 10
7              | 20                  | A20                 | OPW269              | 15
8              | 20                  | A20                 | DUW987              | 65
9              | 20                  | v90                 | OWQ897              | 47



**condition_types BEFORE ADDING SUMIF TO TABLE**
Transactions   | Type                | Product Dimensions  |
-------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | 
customer_1     | ABC                 | 50                  | 
customer_1     | DEF                 | F80                 |
customer_1     | GHI                 | JBH148              | 


**condition_types AFTER ADDING SUMIF TO TABLE**
Transactions   | Type                | Product Dimensions  | sum_of_sales
-------------- | ------------------- | ------------------- | -------------
customer_1     | ABC                 | 50                  | 220
customer_1     | DEF                 | F80                 | 200
customer_1     | GHI                 | JBH148              | 20

Define the sumif function
def sumif(row, value_column):
    if row['Type'] == "ABC":
        filtered_data = sales_data.loc[
            (sales_data['Product_dimension_4'] == row['Product Dimensions'])
        ]
    elif row['Type'] == "DEF" and row['Product Dimensions'] in sales_data['Product_dimension_2'].unique():
        filtered_data = sales_data.loc[
            (sales_data['Product_dimension_2'] == row['Product Dimensions'])
        ]

    elif row['Type'] == "GHI" and row['Product Dimensions'] in sales_data['Product_dimension_3'].unique():
        filtered_data = sales_data.loc[
            (sales_data['Product_dimension_3'] == row['Product Dimensions'])
        ]

    else:
        return 0  # Return 0 instead of an empty string for consistency
    
    return filtered_data[value_column].sum()

Apply the sumif function using loc
condition_types['sum_of_sales'] = condition_types.apply(lambda row: sumif(row, value_column="sum_of_sales"), axis=1)

I hope this is clear enough and the example is not too complicated.

This question has an answer which may be appropriate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65235226/excel-sumif-equivalent-in-pandas

@Dinks123 The answer uses the same approach as i am. It is just too slow

Use np.where for the IF part, then np.sum, that should be fast enough.

For a more general approach, you can melt the sales_data to get a relationship between 'Product Dimensions' and 'sum_of_sales', then groupby on 'Product Dimensions', aggregate with sum, and merge it on conditions_data:
sales_data = (
    pd.melt(
        sales_data,
        id_vars=["sum_of_sales"],
        value_vars=sales_data.filter(like="Product Dimension").columns,
        value_name="Product Dimensions",
    )
    .groupby("Product Dimensions", as_index=False)["sum_of_sales"]
    .sum()
)

condition_types = condition_types.merge(sales_data, how="left")

  Transactions Type Product Dimensions  sum_of_sales
0   customer_1  ABC                 50           220
1   customer_1  DEF                F80           200
2   customer_1  GHI             JBH148            20


But if each 'Type' must respect a relationship with a specific 'Product Dimension' column, you can create a mapping and also use 'Type' to group and merge:
m = {
    "Product Dimension 4": "ABC",
    "Product Dimension 2": "DEF",
    "Product Dimension 3": "GHI",
}

sales_data = pd.melt(
    sales_data,
    id_vars=["Transactions", "sum_of_sales"],
    value_vars=sales_data.filter(like="Product Dimension").columns,
    var_name="Product Dimension Type",
    value_name="Product Dimensions",
)

sales_data["Type"] = sales_data["Product Dimension Type"].map(m)

sales_data = sales_data.groupby(["Product Dimensions", "Type"], as_index=False)[
    "sum_of_sales"
].sum()

condition_types = condition_types.merge(
    sales_data, on=["Product Dimensions", "Type"], how="left"
)

Output is the same for the provided data, but may differ if you have repeated values in different 'Product Dimension' columns.

Thank you e-motta! This works like an absolute charm :-)

I'd suggest reframing your approach, and this is based on the conditions you shared. If I understand the question shared above, you are mapping entries in the Type column to specific columns in the sales_data DataFrame - essentially 'ABC' maps to 'Product_Dimension_4', 'DEF' maps to 'Product_Dimension_2' and 'GHI' maps to 'Product_Dimension_3'. If my assumption is right, then the solution below should offer a faster/efficient route, using Pandas' functions:

df={'Transactions':range(1,10), 
    'Product_Dimension_4': [50,50,50,50,50,50,20,20,20], 
    'Product_Dimension_2':['F80','F80','C36','F80','F80','C36','A20','A20','v90'], 
    'Product_Dimension_3':['ETQ546','SAS978','JBH148','ETq546','SAS978','JBH148','OPW269','DUW987','OWQ897'],
    'sum_of_sales':[80,20,10,80,20,10,15,65,47]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

cond = {'Transactions':['customer_1','customer_1','customer_1'], 
        'Type':['ABC','DEF','GHI'],
        'Product Dimensions':[50,'F80','JBH148']}
cond = pd.DataFrame(cond)

condition=(df
           .filter(like='Product')
           .isin(cond['Product Dimensions'].array)
           .astype(np.int8)
           .rename(columns={'Product_Dimension_4':'ABC', 
                            'Product_Dimension_2':'DEF',
                            'Product_Dimension_3':'GHI'})
           .mask(lambda df: df.eq(1), 
                 df.sum_of_sales,
                 axis=0)
            .sum()
           )
cond.assign(sum_of_sales=cond.Type.map(condition))
  Transactions Type Product Dimensions  sum_of_sales
0   customer_1  ABC                 50           220
1   customer_1  DEF                F80           200
2   customer_1  GHI             JBH148            20

